# PDE on an open ball with prescribed value on some open subsets

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, differential-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

Suppose that we have a $r$-order differential operator  $L:C^r(B^n, \mathbb{R})\to C^0(B^n,\mathbb{R})$  where $B^n $ is the *open* unitary ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (we can assume for simplicity that it is  elliptic).
Let $A\subset B^n$ be *open* subset (in the simplest case we can assume it to be convex).

> How many solutions has the equation
>   $$Lf = 0$$
>   $$f|_{A} = g$$
>   where $g:A\to \mathbb{R}$, $L|_{A} g = 0$ ?.

In the case $L$ is the Cauchy-Riemann operator then solutions are holomorphic functions hence  $g$ determines a unique $f$ defined over the whole ball.  But I expect we can have wilder behaviours for different operators.

This question is motivated by a naive approach to PDEs on manifolds.
Indeed one can in principle think of solving the PDE on one chart $A_1$ getting $g$, then on another chart $A_2$ one should consider some constraint of the above type, namely $f|_{A_1\cap A_2} = g|_{A_1\cap A_2}$, repeating this kind of computation for all the charts we would get a solution defined over the whole manifold.

Comment: I think Aronszajn's theorem ensures uniqueness of continuation, but I can't quite see how at the moment.